# Different storage paths depending on checkout branch with Delta Live Tables

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

How can I change the storage location depending on what branch I am working on.  For example, I'd like the storage location when running a DLT pipeline on my feature branch to be different from the storage location when running the pipeline on a development branch.

Comment: Three (undeveloped) options I can think of: 1. Looks like you can set both the storage location and the path to source files (I assume including branch) in the workflow JSON. https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/settings.html#configure-source-code-libraries 2. Use the schema setting in the workflow job to define which schema to work in 3. You could have two completely different workspaces permanently set up to run different codebases and their associated storage. . For options 1 & 2 you'd need some kind of process to put correct values in the JSON config (i.e. API)

Comment: This popped up in "related questions" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524713/how-to-separate-delta-live-tables-production-and-development-targets-and-repo-br?rq=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to create a separate DLT pipeline per branch. Each branch will have different DLT pipeline settings that will point to different schemas and locations - that approach is [recommended by the DLT docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/testing.html#specify-a-target-schema-during-all-development-lifecycle-phases).

[Following repo](https://github.com/alexott/dlt-files-in-repos-demo) has an example of doing that with Terraform. Or you can use [Databricks Asset Bundles](https://www.databricks.com/resources/demos/tours/data-engineering/databricks-asset-bundles) - it may also simplify the promotion of code between branches/environments.